# Distributing (for free) defunct software with valid license

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, software

I'm thinking about creating and distributing for free a virtual image with Ubuntu that has installed the latest original software from a defunct software provider with valid (paid) licenses.

From what I've [read](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/5913/what-happens-to-ip-owned-by-a-defunct-company), the intellectual property (IP) is (might be) transferred to GoPro in this instance, but I'm not exactly sure this is the case.

Is it possible to distribute the above virtual machine without breaking the copyright or any other law? The software provider is [kolor](https://ivrpa.org/news/gopro-kills-kolor/).

Comment: This is almost certainly a copyright violation, since the IP of Kolor is owned by GoPro. You would need their permission before doing this. The IP of Kolor was transferred to GoPro upon it's acquisition of Kolor.

Comment: @RonBeyer how would one go about checking this? - that the IP was transferred upon acquisition.

Comment: GoPro is public, the terms of the acquisition may be publicly available, I'd try searching on EDGAR first. But in general any wholly-owned subsidiaries IP will belong to the parent company upon operations being ceased.

Comment: @RonBeyer thank you so much!

Comment: It is legal in some jurisdictions to resell licenses, but obviously only once. You can probably also give it away for free, once.

Comment: What does the license of your copy of Kolor say about redistribution?